# HTML5 Video link not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, webrtc

I have the following code for viewing my webcam directly via a publicly accessible link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>webRTC Test</title>
</head>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function init()
    {
        if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia)
        {

            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({video:true}, onSuccess, onFail);

        } 
        else
        {
            alert('webRTC not available');
        }

    }

    function onSuccess(stream)
    {
        document.getElementById('camFeed').src = webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
        var src = document.getElementById('camFeed').getAttribute('src');
        document.getElementById('streamLink').href = src;
    }

    function onFail()
    {
        alert('could not connect stream');
    }


</script>
<body onload = "init();" style="background-color:#ababab;">
    <div style="width:352px; height:625px; margin:0 auto; background-color:#fff;">
        <div>
            <video id ="camFeed" width="320" height="240" autoplay>
            </video>
        </div>
        <div>
            <canvas id="photo" width="320" height="240">
            </canvas>
        </div>


        <div style="margin: 0 auto; width:82px;">
            <a id="streamLink">Visit Stream</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The link generated in the anchor tag is something like:

```
blob:http%3A//sitename.com/7989e43a-334r-4319-b9c5-9dfu00b00cd0
```

And upon visiting chrome tells me "Oops! This link appears to be broken."

Help appreciated!

Comment: What is the _actual_ problematic link?

Comment: <a id ="streamLink"> Visit Stream </a> This link goes to that blob url and breaks when visited...its also the only link in the code i believe. Thanks!

Comment: Poor choice of words on my part. What is the URL?

Answer (score 1):

The [File API spec](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/) defines `URL.createObjectURL`. There are a couple of sections that make what you're trying to do impossible in a browser that follows the spec.

- [Section 11.5](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#originOfBlob) says:

  > The origin of a Blob URI must be the origin of the script that called `URL.createObjectURL`. **Blob URIs must only be valid within this origin**.

  In other words, the URIs returned by `createObjectURL` can only be used within the context of the website that created them (see [RFC6454: The Web Origin Concept](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454) for a more precise definition of what the HTML specs mean by “origin”). You can't visit a URL returned by `createObjectURL` directly.
- [Section 11.6](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#lifeTime) says:

  > This specification adds an additional unloading document cleanup step: user agents must revoke any Blob URIs created with `URL.createObjectURL` from within that document.

  This means that even if you could visit the URL directly, as soon you you leave the page that called `createObjectURL` the URL that was created ceases to exist.

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that you’re using/testing your code at **HTTP** or **HTTPs** protocols --- because `URL.createObjectURL` has some issues at `file://` protocol --- and it can’t be able to generate right BLOB for your video while using **file://**  ---- !!!

Answer (score 0):

**Your code won't work on localhost or your machine alone.**

> All you need is, upload this HTML document on the Net(just in case you are wondering on how to get Hosting for yourself, then try checkout Dropbox, you can upload your HTML page publicly and get access via Public Link for free or try some other product or simply get hosting for yourself). As you can see that this example http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/ works perfectly in chrome, though the code that it is utilising is the same as yours. I hope this solution is of some help to your and others searching for an answer to this bug.

Also, you can then use an iframe to get access to the video element to perform operations on it.